# Spinnaker GCE Autoscaling

Tags: spinnaker

How do you create an autoscaling GCE server group in Spinnaker? In capacity it just has number of instances and I cannot see anything that mentions autoscaling. This should be possible since GCE instance groups can be told to autoscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select a GCE server group, the right-hand side details pane has a link to 'Create new autoscaling policy' in the Autoscaling section.

Once you create the policy, you can edit it via the same set of controls.

A configured autoscaler will be inherited when you clone a server group as well.

Thanks,
-Matt

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for it in the form for creating the server group. I guess it is considered an independent resource and is created separately.

Comment: I was also looking for the ability to define autoscaling policy from a pipeline stage. It doesn't seem like it's possible.